# How to access node set that has been stored in a variable? (XSLT 2.0)

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to figure out why this XSLT isn't working the way I expect it to. Briefly, I want to store a set of XML elements in a variable, and then access them later. The following is an example of the problem.

Given the input XML:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <wd:Report_Entry>
      <wd:Employee_ID>123</wd:Employee_ID>
      <wd:Primary_Address>
         <wd:Address_Line_1>PO BOY 123</wd:Address_Line_1>
         <wd:Address_Line_2>12345 Road Street</wd:Address_Line_2>
         <wd:City>CityTown</wd:City>
         <wd:Use_For>
            <wd:type>PHYSICAL_ADDRESS</wd:type>
         </wd:Use_For>
      </wd:Primary_Address>
   </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

...and a transform like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:variable name="PrimaryAddress">
            <xsl:copy-of select="wd:Primary_Address"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$PrimaryAddress/wd:Address_Line_1"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect to get something like: "PO BOY 123" but instead, I get nothing at all. When I change the value-of statement to select only the variable, like this: "<xsl:value-of select="$PrimaryAddress"/>"
...I get data:

```
     PO BOY 123
     12345 Road Street
     CityTown
     
        PHYSICAL_ADDRESS
```

How do I use the variable I've created to access the child elements like "Address_Line_1"?

Answer (score 1):

The magic works... as soon as I'd posted this question, I stumbled on another answer. I'm not sure if it's the "correct" answer, so please provide another answer if you have more information.

All I did was change my variable declaration to

```
<xsl:variable name="PrimaryAddress" as="element()">
```

Adding the `as='element()'` attribute seems to have done the trick. Now I can browse the variable with XPath expressions, as expected.

Comment: If you create a variable without `@as` to declare the type and do not use `@select` but provide content inside the `xsl:variable` then it will be a `document-node()` - so your original code didn't select the value because the XPath was off (would need to be `$PrimaryAddress/wd:Primary_Address/wd:Address_Line_1` or `$PrimaryAddress/*/wd:Address_Line_1` or `$PrimaryAddress//wd:Address_Line_1`.  See the spec for details: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variable-values